# Symfony Doctrine Flush Returning Null

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to create a system that will recreate a new shift when given a date array example [0,3,4] for the same day, 3 days away and 4 days away. When I create a single shift I am able to persist and flush to the database with no problem at all.

My Issue is when I create my $newShifts in a forloop persist them and once all are persisted (9 for example) I go to flush and get the following.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO guard_shift (shift_start, shift_end, actual_shift_start, actual_shift_end, approved, deletedAt, user_id, admin_id, site_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, false, null, 1, 1, 8]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'shift_start' cannot be null",
"class": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\NotNullConstraintViolationException
```

If I dd $newShift->getStartShift before the flush I get 9 start times.

This Gist is both the controller endpoint and my helper combined in one file for ease of sharing.

https://gist.github.com/George-Farrell/86524c53f3218dbd1cbfd003b7666df6

Answer (score 0):

The code in the gist looks very raw and needs refactoring to more obvious steps and more small functions for the sake of readability.
My suggestion is that this function is the root of the problem:
when $clashingId is true, you can't persist a new shift, because the result of the function is already returned.

```
    private function flushShift($admin,$shiftStart,$shiftFinish,$user,$site)
{
    $newShift = new GuardShift();
    $newShift->setAdmin($admin);
    $newShift->setShiftStart($this->timestamp->reverseTransform(strtotime($shiftStart)));
    $newShift->setShiftEnd($this->timestamp->reverseTransform(strtotime($shiftFinish)));
    $newShift->setUser($user);
    $newShift->setSite($site);

    $clashingId = $this->isShiftClashing(
        $shiftStart,
        $shiftFinish,
        $admin,
        $user
    );

    if ($clashingId == true) {
        $clash = $this->entityManager->getRepository(GuardShift::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $clashingId]);
        $data = $this->serialize->serialize($clash, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks());

        return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_CONFLICT, [], true);
    }
    $this->entityManager->persist($newShift);
}
```

Comment: Even putting a `DD('I made it');` in the clashing function, it never reaches it so it's not that I don't think.